# How connect multiple Observable in chain

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I'm using TheMovieDb API https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api and if I want to authenticate, I must use three steps to do this - get token, create session using token and get session id. I want to use 3 `Observable` to do this, but I don't know how can chain `Observables` to do this.

My `Observables`

```
public interface AuthenticationService {

@GET("authentication/token/new")
Observable<Token> getMdbToken();

@GET("authentication/token/validate_with_login")
Observable<Token> createSessionId(Credentials credentials,String token);

@GET("authentication/session/new")
Observable<Session> getSessionId(String token);
}
```

Is this possible to chain `Observables` to make one `Observable`? I'm not have a experience to use `Observables`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) operator is ideal for this. Just compose 3 observables:

```
getMdbToken()
        .flatMap(new Func1<Token, Observable<Token>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Token> call(Token token) {
                return createSessionId(credentials, token);
            }
        }).flatMap(new Func1<Token, Observable<Session>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Session> call(Token token) {
        return getSessionId(String token); ;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But it this will be do in particular sequence? For example, is possible that getSessionId will be start before createSessionId?

Comment: It is not guaranteed in general case. `flatMap` does not guarantee the order (see [diagram](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/images/flatMap.c.png)). If you must ensure the order look for `concatMap` ([diagram](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/images/concatMap.png)). However in your case it is not relevant, because every `Observable` in your sequence generates only one `onNext` event.